# Designing database for multi-level dropdown menu

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, database-design, drop-down-menu

I know how to create a multi-level dropdown menu with HTML and CSS, that's not a problem. However, I'm in need of a simple cms, easy to the end-user with absolutely no technical skills and easy enough to create sites for me. It should also be lightweight.

Concrete5 was a good example of easy user interface for the end user, until it's last version. It's way too cluttered now. So I couldn't find a single one, and started to create my own.

So, I'm reinventing the wheel (and I'm pretty much half-way through) to create my own cms. However, I'm facing a problem I could resolve on my own, but I want to make sure everything is fast and done in the best way possible.

---

**Question starts from here.**

How should I design my database to allow dropdown navigation menus? Considering these things:

My `pages` table looks like this simplified:

```
pID |  pName  | pIsChildTo
 1     Front       0
 2     Page2       0
 3     SubTo2      2
```

So as you can see, I thought that I could just list when a page is a sub-page to another page, but when I started writing the code for navigation menu creation, I realized that it's not that simple. There's no way that I know of, that I could possibly check for child pages when I'm looping through the database and create a submenu (take note that I'm using bootstrap for the navigation).

Sure, if I was lazy, I could add a column to my table, to make it look like this:

```
pID |  pName  | pIsChildTo | pHasChildren
 1     Front       0              0
 2     Page2       0              1
 3     SubTo2      2              0
```

And when looping through the navigation when creating it, I could just check the `pIsChildTo` value, and if it's `1`, do things with that.

```
foreach($db->fetchAll() as $r){
  if($r['pHasChildren'] != 0){ ?>
    <!-- insert dropdown logic here -->
  <?php }
  else{ ?>
    <li class=""><a href="?id=<?php echo $r['pID']; ?>"><?php echo $r['pName']; ?></a></li>
  <?php }
}
```

But that seems to the dirty way. Should I change my database design a bit, and if yes, what would I need to do?

Comment: That's wrong. Is it correct the way you have at db, simply on your db select add a column (only in query) with the number of children (taken from a subquery)

Comment: @MarcoMura could you explain a bit further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended Edition:

You are right on your db. But you can work around your needs, you need to know if a voice got children? ok =)

Let's say you've got this query to obtain all your menu:

```
SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY ....
```

You can know if each voice got children this way:

```
SELECT p.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages WHERE pIsChildTo =  p.pID) as children FROM pages p
```

EDIT:
Without real need it's best to not change a db that's working. A lot of people use a lot of data for menu, you can use short data for dropdown menu too, but you need to know exactly what you want =)

EDIT2:

```
SELECT p.*, //Select all pages field
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages WHERE pIsChildTo =  p.pID) as children //This is a subquery
//i'm counting all the records that have the actual id on pIsChildTo field and putting the result
//into a field called children (you will find one for each row).
FROM pages p //p is a table alias.
```

if i launch the subquery alone i will find all the records that have as example 2 as "parent", that said, if we use it a subquery we can obtain something near what you need.

Comment: Can you break the query for me, I can't really understand it.. :)

Comment: Done the breaking and explained

Comment: Well that's interesting. I'll give it a try later, I got to run now.

Comment: Hey it works! :D It lists my "Front" page to have 3 children and "Page2" to have one children, which is right as all pages are children to main page. Thanks!

Comment: Lol, next time ask for a sql solution when possible ;)